# restarting tomcat instance with bamboo using a function

Tags: shell, unix, tomcat, ssh, bamboo

I'm trying to run a function that we have to recycle our tomcat instance when doing a deploy to tomcat via bamboo. I thought that we would be able to use bamboo's ssh task to call our function `tomcat recycle`.  I am able to run the function ssh connected to the box via putty but in bamboo we get the message:

ksh: tomcat: not found

Does anybody have any experience restarting tomcat automatically via bamboo? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

To restart tomcat via Bamboo

Create a ssh task -

You should be having tomcat service file in /etc/init.d (if you are using redhat)

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat start
/etc/init.d/tomcat stop
/etc/init.d/tomcat restart
```

should work